# How to create folders using file names and then move files into folders?

Tags: python, perl, bash, unix, batch-file

I have hundreds of text files in a folder named using this kind of naming convention:

```
Bandname1 - song1.txt
Bandname1 - song2.txt
Bandname2 - song1.txt
Bandname2 - song2.txt
Bandname2 - song3.txt
Bandname3 - song1.txt
..etc.
```

I would like to create folders for different bands and move according text files into these folders. How could I achieve this using bash, perl or python script?

Comment: Would you consider writing a script to do this by yourself and posting it here? I think it would be much more instructive if people commented on that rather write one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**gregseth**'s answer will work, just replace `trim` with `xargs`.  You could also eliminate the `if` test by just using `mkdir -p`, for example:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    band=$(echo "$f" | cut -d'-' -f1 | xargs)
    mkdir -p "$band"
    mv "$f" "$band"
done
```

Strictly speaking the `trim` or `xargs` shouldn't even be necessary, but `xargs` will at least remove any extra formatting, so it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessary to use trim or xargs:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    band=${f% - *}
    mkdir -p "$band"
    mv "$f" "$band"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

with Perl

```
use File::Copy move;
while (my $file= <*.txt> ){
    my ($band,$others) = split /\s+-\s+/ ,$file ;
    mkdir $band;
    move($file, $band);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked for a specific script, but if this is for organizing your music, you might want to check out **[EasyTAG](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/)**. It has extremely specific and powerful rules that you can customize to organize your music however you want:

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/images/screenshot-gtk2/screenshot_sw_scan_tag.png))</sub>

This rule says, "assume my file names are in the structure "[artist] - [album title]/[track number] - [title]". Then you can tag them as such, or move the files around to any new pattern, or do pretty much anything else.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for f in *.txt
do
  band=$(echo "$f" | cut -d'-' -f1 | trim)
  if [ -d "$band" ]
  then
    mkdir "$band"
  fi
  mv "$f" "$band"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but my Bash (I'm on mac 10.6.2) says that 
-bash: trim: command not found
I tried textutil::text but I got same answer

Answer (score 0):

This Python program assumes that the source files are in `data` and that the new directory structure should be in `target` (and that it already exists).

The key point is that `os.path.walk` will traverse the `data` directory structure and call `myVisitor` for each file.

```
import os
import os.path

sourceDir = "data"
targetDir = "target"

def myVisitor(arg, dirname, names):
    for file in names:
        bandDir = file.split("-")[0]
        newDir = os.path.join(targetDir, bandDir)
        if (not os.path.exists(newDir)):
            os.mkdir(newDir)

        newName = os.path.join(newDir, file)
        oldName = os.path.join(dirname, file)

        os.rename(oldName, newName)

os.path.walk(sourceDir, myVisitor, None)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ls |perl -lne'$f=$_; s/(.+?) - [^-]*\.txt/$1/; mkdir unless -d; rename $f, "$_/$f"'
```